# Problem with Grub / Can't start Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu

Today I installed Kubuntu 17.04 from my live USB, integrity verified, and succeded, but whwnever I try to start I get [this](http://prnt.sc/f6rkpl) screen.
I got  [this](http://paste2.org/ObJnVbdy)  report from boot-repair.
I can't start live in (U)EFI mode nor I can put on legacy boot from BIOS.

vendor: ASUS
model: F200MA-KX552b

Comment: if I try to update grub I get this error: "failed to get canonical path of `aufs'."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least part of the problem is caused by BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode vs. EFI/UEFI-mode boot conflicts:

- Your disk has a BIOS-mode version of GRUB in the MBR. This appears to be valid as far as the Boot Repair analysis is concerned, but this analysis only goes so far.
- Your disk uses a [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), which means that Windows *must* boot in EFI mode, not in BIOS mode.
- You have EFI-mode versions of both GRUB and the Windows boot loader installed on the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)
- Your Boot Repair output indicates that the computer was booted in BIOS mode when you ran Boot Repair. This means it provides no `efibootmgr` output, which might be helpful in repairing the installation; but there are things you can try even without that....

You should first understand that mixed-mode (EFI/BIOS boot) installations are possible, but add a layer of complexity that's better avoided. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for all the gory details.

Given that Windows is installed in EFI mode, your best bet is to first *disable your CSM,* as described on the page I've just referenced. Details of how to do this vary from one computer to another, so I can't provide step-by-step instructions. Chances are you enabled the CSM either in a semi-random debugging effort or because you followed some bad advice on the Internet, so you may know where the setting is already. (It may have been called "legacy boot support" or something similar.)

Once you disable the CSM, you could try Boot Repair again. If it's launched in EFI mode rather than BIOS mode, it might work. You can check your boot mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode.

If Boot Repair doesn't help, then I recommend you try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) You can download the CD-R or USB flash drive image, prepare it, and boot with it. After testing that it boots Windows, boot into Ubuntu. If this all works, then you can install the `refind` package (`sudo apt-get install refind`); or you can download the Debian package or use my PPA to get a slightly more recent version. rEFInd does not need GRUB to boot, so the failure of GRUB's configuration will not affect rEFInd.